# javafx form not appear

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

When I run the javafx programme not showing javafx windows form that I created.console shows like below picture..

here is my code:

```
    package Employee;                                                              

import java.io.IOException;                                                    

import javafx.application.Application;                                         
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;                                                 
import javafx.scene.Scene;                                                     
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;                                         
import javafx.stage.Stage;                                                     

public class main extends Application {                                        

    private Stage primaryStage;                                                
    private BorderPane mainLayout;                                             
    @Override                                                                  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {                 
        this.primaryStage=primaryStage;                                        
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("My windows");                              
        showMainView();                                                        

    }                                                                          
    private void showMainView() throws IOException                             
    {                                                                          
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();                                    
        loader.setLocation(main.class.getResource("view/Mainview.fxml"));      
        mainLayout=loader.load();                                              
        Scene scene=new Scene(mainLayout);                                     
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);                                          

    }                                                                          


    public static void main(String[] args) {                                   
        launch(args);                                                          
    }
```

}

and after execute it console shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Rxn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Your mainLayout in your FXML is not a `BorderPane`
- You are missing a call to [show](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show--):

  `primaryStage.show();`

Comment: Looks like you answered while I was still reading the question!

Answer (score 0):

is the root of your `view/Mainview.fxml` a BorderPane? If not you will get a ClassCastException like the one you are seeing. Even if it is, you may need to write that line as an explicit cast like this: `mainLayout=(BorderPane)loader.load()`  Also, you will need to make a call to `primaryStage.show()` after you set the scene, otherwise your window won't show up.